# Count and sort commands used in history

Tags: bash, cut

I have a text file with bunch of commands, for example:

```
ls -l
/bin/bash/
cat file.txt
bash
cat somethingElse
```

What I have to do is, get the names of commands (`ls`, `cat`, `bash`) and count them. I already did this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

This works almost as I would like to--output is:

```
1 bash
1 /bin/bash
2 cat
1 ls
```

The only thing is wrong here, it has to IGNORE ABSOLUTE paths, so the output must look like this

```
2 bash
2 cat
1 cat
```

I was trying with a while loop with a if statement in it which checks if there is a "/" in a line, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` you can say `print $1` to print the first word. However, you want the name alone. For this, you can use `basename`:

```
$ basename "/bin/bash"
bash
```

Then it is a matter of calling `basename` from `awk`. All together:

```
$ awk '{system("basename "$1)}' a
ls
bash
cat
bash
cat
```

Then you can pipe to `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ awk '{system("basename "$1)}' a | sort | uniq -c
      2 bash
      2 cat
      1 ls
```

Comment: Thank you, working as intended! Is there a way to "remake" your command, so it also takes pipes as a part of a command? 
Lets say there is a line which contains: cat file.txt | sort | uniq -c, and it will also count sort and uniq as commands that are counted and printed in cmd?

Comment: Mmmm maybe you should replace pipes with new lines beforehand: `tr '|' '\n' < file`

Comment: awk '{system("basename "$1)}' "${@: -1}" | tr '|' '\n' < "${@: -1}" | sort | uniq -c 

I tried like this, but it just doubles the output.

btw ${@: -1} is the last argument, which is the file.

Comment: no.. Damn professors.. i managed to do it with cut, but i have problems with sort.